# How to display Multiple price currencies in product page?

Tags: magento2, product, price, currency

I want to display 2 currencies at a same time on product page, just like `$50` and `AED200` something like this : https://miatlantic.ae/ws-c3850-24t-s

Answer (score 0):

**Note :** Im not sure if it's a best way.

1. Stores > Configuration > Currency Setup (`USD` & `AED`)
   [image]
2. Stores > Currency rates

[image]

3. > app/design/frontend/{Theme}/{name}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <block class="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Extracurrency" name="extra-currency-price" template="Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/extra.phtml" />
       </body>
   </page>
   ```
4. copy `default.phtml` from :

   > Vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

   into :

   > app/design/frontend/{Theme}/{name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

   Then add inside :

   ```
   <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('extra-currency-price'); ?>
   ```
5. > app/design/frontend/{Theme}/{name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/extra.phtml

   ```
   <div class="additional-price"><?php echo $block->getProductPriceByCurrency('AED') ?></div>
   ```
6. You need to add this block in your module

   > app/code/{Vendor}/{modulename}/Block/Extracurrency.php

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block;

   class Extracurrency extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
   {
       protected $_storeManager;
       protected $_objectManager;
       protected $_currency;
       protected $_registry;

       public function __construct(
           \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
           \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
           \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
           \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency,
           \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
           array $data = []
       ) {
           $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
           $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
           $this->_currency = $currency;
           $this->_registry = $registry;
           parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }

       /**
        * Get product price by currency code
        *
        * @param $code
        * @return mixed
        *
        * @autor @m
        */
       public function getProductPriceByCurrency($code) {
           $currentCurrency = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode();
           $currency = $this->_currency->load($currentCurrency);
           $product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
           $currencyModelInstance = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency');
           $availableCurrency = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getAvailableCurrencyCodes(); //USD, AED

           if (in_array($code, $availableCurrency)) {
               $currencySymbol = $currencyModelInstance->load($code)->getCurrencySymbol();
               $priceConvert = $currency->convert($product->getPrice(), $code);
               $result = $currencyModelInstance->format($priceConvert, ['precision'=> 2, 'symbol' => $currencySymbol], false, false);
           } else {
               $result =  null;
           }
           return $result;  
       }
   }
   ```
7. ```
   php bin/magento s:d:c
   php bin/magento c:f
   ```

Result : 
[image]